# Where can I start reading about how to this in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I will first explain it in SQL terms, since this would be easy to do without Core Data (probably even simpler in Core Data but I have just started).

I have a table lets say 'A' that has a many to many relationship to table 'B'. Table 'B' only have 4 rows, which are static, just as a table with zipcodes would be. I also has a table 'C' which is exactly the same only with another content. So table B and C are connected to A with join-tables.

So in Core Data I would make 3 entities and set up the relationships between them. That part I understand. However what do I do when the user saves a record in table A, and whatever the relations to B and C is? Because obviously I do only want those 4 distinct rows in table B and C. Do I query to find the objects in table B and C and then "links" those to the new record in A?

If this makes any sense I would appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a person who always starts with official docs before anything else: Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) has a [quick start tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) on Core Data for the iPhone. It's very, very basic but covers things like managed object models, the managed object context and how to perform CRUD on some geolocation data and display it in a table view. You might want to check it out, then read the other resources that the Programming Guide links to.

Here is more

http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/advanced-iphone-development/id407243032#ls=1

http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/iphone-application-programming/id384233222#ls=1

Answer (score 0):

Another link you could try

[Getting started with CoreData](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started)